# How to close only child on click of a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mdiparent

I have created MDI form using [CodePlex DLL](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/), I have added a WPF user control and opened it as a child with below code:

```
MainMdiContainer.Children.Add(new MdiChild()
        {
            Title = " Employee Master",
            Height = 300,
            Width = 500,
            //Here CustomerMaster is the class that you have created for mainWindow.xaml user control.
            Content = new EmpMaster()
        });
```

Now I want to close only that child form (WPF User Control) on Click of a button.I have used following code on that button click:

```
Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
```

But that code close the program along with all opened window and MDI parent also. How can I close only that particular WPF user control on button click?

Comment: What happens if you do `this.Close()`?

Comment: Unable to get that this.close() in visual studio for WPF UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, I have called below lines of code on that button click:

```
MainWindow mainWind = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
mainWind.MainMdiContainer.Children.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that framework but I suspect that an MDI child is not a `Window`. When you call `Window.GetWindow(this).Close();` you close the main window and therefore terminate the application.

Try to remove the `MdiChild` from the `MainMdiContainer`:

```
var child = new MdiChild() { ... };
MainMdiContainer.Children.Add(child);
// Later
MainMdiContainer.Children.Remove(child);
```

Comment: It is .Net 4.0 Framework, And adding child on the MDI container is on the MainWindow.xaml page, and removal of that child will be called from Child form, and on that form I am unableto get "MainMdiContainer" object to remove child

Comment: I did not talk about .NET but the external MDI framework/library. Anyway. Why are you not able to access it? Just make it public. Or provide some public method in the main window, or an event in the child, or a command in the view model. This is not really a question about MDI but how to make different UI parts communicate.

Comment: Sebastian request you to once go through the link in my question, you will get the complete info about framework of dll and implementation method of MDI. Its not winForm MDI, Its WPF Page as Parent MDI and WPF user control as child page.

Comment: Please refer Below link I have implemented exactly:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/implement-mdi-multiple-document-interface-with-menu-contro/